# Format for getting clear directions on data parameters from users

Tags: requirements, data

As part of my job, I regularly get ad-hoc requests from users for snapshots of our very large database. However, there's no fixed format for delivering these and they usually come through in the form of bullet-pointed text, for example:

- All customers
- All active in last 0-24 months (including non-contactable customers)
- All committed

In this instance, "committed" is a flag, and "active/non-contactable" is both a text-based status and a dynamic status based on their last purchase. So this request could be interpreted as:

- All customers who made a purchase in the last 24 months, regardless of status
- All customers who have a "active" or "non-contactable" status regardless of last purchase.
- One of the above and then "either" having a committed flag, or "and" having a committed flag.

I won't labour the point - you see the problem. And it's worth adding that the possible range of parameters is quite large. Normally I have to talk to the requestor and go through a rigmarole of explaining the problem and trying to clarify the requirements.

This situation can't be that uncommon. Is there a more effective way of capturing these details, with a checkbox-style grid or other visual aid? Does anyone have any examples of experience of useful solutions?

Comment: Expose an API to query the database?  This API could include some basic business logic so that the users get the data in the format they expect and not in the format its stored in.

Comment: @MetaFight Sadly the possible range of requirements are just too complex for this, otherwise I'd have done it a long time ago and let them get on with it themselves :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all part of the inefficiencies, inconveniences and potential for errors that are ad hoc requests. These are all compounded the further away from the data the requester is. Good luck with the "big picture" people.

Early on, I don't see how you're going to avoid this, but as the same person makes other requests and the more requests you get in general, you should start noticing some trends and overlapping of information.

The goal should be to educate others and yourself to the point where these requests (think of them as conversations) can get to the point sooner. You can't get away with knowing nothing about your domain/business. Eventually, they won't expect to have to explain the same things to you over and over.

**Data Dictionary** - start creating one of these so everyone can get on the same page of what everything means. Business rules may make up part of the definitions. If possible, try to get everyone to use standard terminology. This can be a problem with different departments. This way you can refer to the dictionary early on in its adoption.

**Get Background Information**

- who?  This may determine how careful you have to be and the process you may have to take to accomplish the report. You can send something to the accounting department so they can review and check your figures, but if it is going into a presentation for the head of sales, you ore someone else will need to test.
- what? These are the detailed questions about the requirements you're already asking.
- when? - Don't forget to ask when they need it. Too many people assume everything is a rush job just because someone just asked. If they are in a hurry, you may need to put some requirements on their time for further questions and preliminary checking of the data.
- where/how? - To me this is more about what format they want the request. Returning a set of data to be pulled into a spreadsheet for analysis can be very different than a printed report with a lot of formatting and pretty colors for presentation.
- **why?** - This is very important. Don't let people think this is some kind of push back from you, but to gain more understanding so you can make informed suggestions. Maybe they need to defend why they are using the company's resources and time and I don't know if that is up to you.

Maybe you can make some sort of request document with check boxes for the typical stuff, but really it is going to be a back and forth process until you understand what you want.  Never be surprised as you go through this process that there will be things the requester didn't ask for or know. Sometimes they have to see the report to trigger new ideas.  "I didn't realize we sold that many cars last month. To shorten the report can you aggregate it by make/model?" Happens all the time. And if there is room for one more column, they'll eventually ask you to fill it.